# Using python to export requirements from PDFs to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pdf

This probably sounds like it's been asked before, but I could not find an answer to my question specifically.

I have around 45 PDF documents that list requirements for our company. These are structrued like so:

32. If the undertaking has  set GHG emission reductio n targets3, [draft] ESRS 2 D C-T and the
    following requirements shall apply :
    (a) GHG emission reduction  targets shall ;
    (b) GHG emission reduction targets shall be disclosed for Sco pe 1, 2, and 3 GHG
    emissions.  The undertaking shall  ;
    (c) the undertaking shall disclose its  ;
33. The undertaking shall provide information on its energy consumption and mix.

I found a way to extract the text in Python, using PyPDF2 and PdfReader.

However, now I want each requirment to be a seperate line in Excel or in a dataframe.

Is there any script I can use to store each requirement (starting with a number and a dot, so like 32. and 33.) in a new row? And do this for 45 PDFs?

Comment: I received a response with a snippet of script that looked useful, but I was not able to respond/implement this right away. Did the commenter remove it? I had follow up questions, sorry for not getting back sooner.

Answer (score 1):

import pdftables_api
conversion = pdftables_api.Client('API KEY')
conversion.xlsx("pdf_file_path", "output_file_path")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).